# Calculating dependent consecutive probability using JS for an n amount of times

Tags: javascript, probability

I have an array containing n number of types of marbles, here is a simplified example:

```
 let marbles = [
   {variable: “Green marbles”, text: “Green marble”, amount: 10},
   {variable: “Yellow marbles”, text: “Yellow marble”, amount: 12},
   {variable: “Pink marbles”, text: “Pink marble”, amount: 8}
  ]
```

What I’m looking to do with this array is to calculate the probability of getting a green or yellow or pink marble consecutively without replacing it (meaning each time a marble is drawn it is substrates).
So here’s an example:

```
in the first pick, the probability of getting a pink marble is: 
8/30.
In the second pick, the probability is now:
7/29 * 8/30
In the third pick, the probability is now: 
6/28 * 7/29 * 8/30
```

And so on.
Ive managed to accomplish this to calculate the probability **with** replacement like  so:

```
let withReplacementArray = []
let i
let total = marbles.reduce((prev, cur)=> {return prev + cur.amount}, 0)
marbles.forEach((cur)=> {
for(i=1; i<=total; i ++) {
   withReplacementArray.push({
     probability: (Math.pow(cur.amount, i))/(Math.pow(total, i)),
     n: i, 
     text: cur.text
   })
 }
})
```

In short, this method will not work for calculating the probability without replacement because it is no longer as simple as raising it to the power of i.
Any suggestions?
Or is there any formula i can follow to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract one from both marble amounts (the type you're interested in, and the total) inside the loop. Rather than powers, keep an outside variable for the cumulative probability of the last loop.

```js
let marbles = [
   {variable: "Green marbles", text: "Green marble", amount: 10},
   {variable: "Yellow marbles", text: "Yellow marble", amount: 12},
   {variable: "Pink marbles", text: "Pink marble", amount: 8}
];

// say we want to pick green
let greenAmount = marbles[0].amount;
let total = marbles.reduce((a, { amount }) => a + amount, 0);

let lastProbability = 1;
while (greenAmount > 0) {
  lastProbability = lastProbability * (greenAmount / total);
  console.log(lastProbability);
  greenAmount--;
  total--;
}
// 10/30
// then 10/30 * 9/29
// etc
```

Comment: how would you make it so that it gives the solutions for each marble?

Comment: Make a loop around the whole code instead of hard-coding the `marbles[0].amount;`

Comment: I tried doing it but im getting issues with the loop as the total is not being reset after each colour

Comment: Calculate the total inside the loop, or save it in a variable outside the loop that doesn't get reassigned